# Maven does not find lucene-regex.jar

Tags: regex, maven, lucene, build-dependencies

I have added **lucene-regex** dependency in my project's **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-regex</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I run `mvn install` I get a `BUILD FAILURE` with the following error:

```
 package org.apache.lucene.search.regex does not exist
```

Maven manages to find **lucene-regex-3.0.3.pom** and copies it in `.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-regex\3.0.3` but fails to find the **.jar** which contains this package.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds strange cause the message says you are using in your code an import on that package. Can you give the full message output of that. Furthermore i have checked maven central (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.lucene|lucene-regex|3.0.3|jar). which contains the dependency you mentioned.